# List filter then List map in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml, ocaml-core

How do you apply a List filter before a List map in OCaml? I'm trying the pipe operator but with no success:

```
let r infile =
match List.tl (In_channel.read_lines infile ) with
| None -> []
| Some body ->
  List.filter body ~f:(fun line -> true)
  |> List.map body ~f:(fun line ->
    match split_on_comma line with
    | _ :: _ :: num :: street :: unit :: city :: _ :: region :: _ ->
      String.strip (num ^ " " ^ addr_case street ^ ", " ^ addr_case city ^ " " ^ region)
    | _ -> assert false)
```

utop is giving me:

"This expression has type string list
  but an expression was expected of type string list -> 'a"

I'm aware the List.filter does nothing at present. I'm simply trying to use it before the List.map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard OCaml List.filter doesn't have the `~f:` parameter. Most likely you're using Core.

I don't have Core set up right now, so I can't test. But one possible problem is that you're using `body` in the `List.map` call. I think you should leave it out. You want to process the result of the `List.filter` expression. You don't want to process body, which is the original value from the match.

Here is a similar expression using the OCaml standard library versions of the functions:

```
# ListLabels.filter [1; 2; 3; 4]
      ~f: (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) |>
  ListLabels.map ~f: (fun x -> x + 10) ;;
- : int list = [12; 14]
```